# Is there a way of getting the classname of a QObject derived class without creating an instantiation of that class?

Tags: c++, qt, metaobject

I'm looking for something like this:

`MyClass::metaObject()->className()`

which doesn't work because at the point where this code is executed, there exists no instantiation of MyClass.

If this is somehow possible, is there a way of getting all names of the classes that have been derived from MyClass?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the [static meta object](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#staticMetaObject-var):

```
 MyClass::staticMetaObject.className()
```

Works!

Comment: @TomášZato Just use `myClassInstance->staticMetaObject().className()`.

Comment: @TomášZato Actually, you probably want to use `metaObject` rather than `staticMetaObject`, to get info about the actual type of the object and not the type of the pointer.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use:

```cpp
obj->metaObject()->className();
```

Comment: This gave me the desired result by returning the name of the actual class and not the base class (as oposed to the accepted answer)